# setText from AsyncTask in onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the following AsyncTask to get some data from a xml file:

```
public class GetTripDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {

    private Context context;
    private String[] details = new String[4];

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    public GetTripDetails (Context parsedContext){
        context = parsedContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
        String activeTrip;

        try {
            sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            activeTrip = sharedpreferences.getString("activeTrip", null); //Liest den Namen des aktiven Trips

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "android/data/com.travip/" + activeTrip + ".trp");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
            myparser.setInput(fis, null);

            int event = myparser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)  {
                String tag_name = myparser.getName();
                switch (event){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(tag_name.equals("trip")){
                            details[0] = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                            details[1] = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "startdate");
                            details[2] = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "enddate");
                            details[3] = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "description");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                event = myparser.next();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return details;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        tv_title.setText(result[0]);
        tv_subtitle.setText(result[1] + " - " + result[2]);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

It produces an null pointer exeption, although tv_title and tv_subtitle are public and the AsyncTask is in the same class. I tried to execute it in onStart() (-> after the TextViews should have been initialized), but it didn't work either. 
Thanks for your advice

**Upadte:**
logcat:

```
08-08 12:09:01.446 22390-22390/com.travip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        Process: com.travip, PID: 22390
                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.travip/com.travip.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                            at com.travip.MainActivity$GetTripDetails.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:192)
                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
                                                            at com.travip.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Overview.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Activities.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Marked.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Map.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Nearby.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
NavigationView navigationView;
String activeMenu;

public ImageView expand_collapse;
public TextView tv_title;
public TextView tv_subtitle;
public View headerLayout;

DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.access_token));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_overview); //Setzt den aktiven Menüeintrag
    activeMenu = "main";

    headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    headerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Ändert das Menü, wenn auf den Header gecklickt wird
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleMenu();
        }
    });

    expand_collapse = (ImageView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.expand_collapse);
    tv_title = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tv_subtitle = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    new GetTripDetails(getApplicationContext()).execute();
}
//Here is the asynctask (see above)
```

}

**Update 2:**
logcat (after initializing TextViews):

```
08-08 12:20:59.008 934-934/com.travip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                    Process: com.travip, PID: 934
                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                        at com.travip.MainActivity$GetTripDetails.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:255)
                                                        at com.travip.MainActivity$GetTripDetails.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:183)
                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

**Update 3:**
nav_header_main.xml (headerLayout of the navigation drawer (Where the TextViews are located)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:id="@+id/nav_header_main" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_top"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="Spanien"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:text="21.3.17 - 1.4.17"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expand_collapse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_expand"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/fragment_overview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have you done findViewById and assigned it to those textviews. Can you add that code?

Comment: are the `TextViews` initialized? Share the NPE.

Comment: share the logcat error

Comment: You have to execute it on OnCreate().  TextViews should be initalized in OnCreate() and after this you have to execute asynctask

Comment: can u post your xml ?

Comment: To avoid memory leak on your context, I recommend you to make your GetTripDetails class static, and replace context param in constructor with an appropriate callback interface who returns your task results to your activity. It'll also certainly resolve your problem, because in your case, no reference of your task is set.

Comment: Mora S. could you please give an example? I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: first define your textviews before calling async task and in oNPostExecute method first line should be super.onPostExecute(result);

Answer (score 1):

To avoid memory leak on your context, I recommend you to make your GetTripDetails class static, and replace context param in constructor with an appropriate callback interface who returns your task results to your activity. It'll also certainly resolve your problem, because in your case, no reference of your task is set.

```
static class GetTripDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    private WeakReference<Callback> callbackRef;

    public GetTripDetails(final Callback callback){
        callbackRef = new WeakReference<>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do your stuff
        return details;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        final Callback callback = callbackRef.get();
        if (callback == null) {
            return;
        }
        callback.onResult(result);
    }

    interface Callback {
        void onResult(String[] result);
    }

}
```

In your activity :

```
private final Callback callback = new Callback() {
    void onResult(String[] result) {
        // set values in your textview..
    } 
}

private GetTripDetails task;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    task = new GetTripDetails(callback);
    task.execute(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example code. I don't know, which callback I should import. Is it "GetTripDetails.Callback" or something else?

Comment: yes this one, you can give it another name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So should I remove the context from public GetTripDetails() or can I keep it. And if I should remove it, how do I get the context for my sharedpreferences?

Comment: yep I didnt paid attention for that. You'd better add SharedPreferences in contructor, than context.

Comment: I tested it but I still get a null pointer exception because of the TextView. If I display the result in a toast, everything is fine

Comment: and you write findViewById(R.id.subtitle), maybe instead of findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle), can you share your activity_main.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151401/discussion-between-p-0g-amm3-and-mora-s).

Comment: No need, your problem is that you should call findViewById(); with the defined android:id params of TextView present in your xml, in your case R.id.title and R.id.subtitle

Comment: To avoid problems of concurrent id name definition, I advise you to always define your ids with a more contextual name, like "@+id/home_header_title" and "@+id/home_header_subtitle"

Comment: Ok finally I figured it out. The id of the subtitle was correct, but the one of the title was not. Thank you very much for solving the issue and for giving good hints.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, you have not attached your textviews with your views by doing `findViewById`

Do it in onCreate

```
tv_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_title_id);
tv_subtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_subtitle_id);
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot it. Sorry for that. I added it, but it still doesn't work. You can see the updated code above. Still, thanks

Comment: Yes, but just the second "part" (starting at "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt ...")

Comment: That should be because of something else. Could you place the logs again

Comment: @p_0g_amm3_ are you sure your textviews with this id are part of your layout activity_main?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use interface for AsyncTask methods.
2. Put TextViews to your AsyncTask in constructor

In your AsyncTask class declare this

```
private TextView tv_title;
private TextView tv_subtitle;
```

And your AsyncTask consructor like this

```
public GetTripDetails (Context parsedContext, TextView tvTitle, TextView tvSubtitle){
    context = parsedContext;
    this.tv_title = tvTitle;
    this.tv_subtitle = tvSubtitle;
}
```

Then run your loader

```
new GetTripDetails(getApplicationContext(), tv_title, tv_subtitle).execute();
```

It'll work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested it, but it didn't work. Still the same issue.