# ProgressDialog in Asynctask not Dismissing when unzipping file is done

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm creating an app that unzips the selected item in the listview. I'm using asynctask to unzip the zip files,so while it unzips the file there's a progressDialog to show the progress of unzipping it. I successfully display the progressDialog but when the unzipping is done the progressDialog is not dismissing and it is stuck there. I tried to search here in stackoverflow that is related to my answer and I even try it on my app but none of them works. pls help.

this is what i have done so far :
Decompress. java

```
public class Decompress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

private final static String TAG = "Decompress";
private String zipFile;
private String location;

ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;
Context ctx;

public Decompress(String zipFile, String location, Context ctx) {
    super();
    this.zipFile = zipFile;
    this.location = location;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    dirChecker("");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    myProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait... Unzipping");
    myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    myProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    myProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params){
    int count = 0;

    try  {
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
        myProgressDialog.setMax(zip.size());
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());
            if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(location +ze.getName());

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int len;
                while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    count++;
                    publishProgress(count);// Here I am doing the update of my progress bar
                }
                fout.close();
                zin.closeEntry();

            }
        }
        zin.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    myProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]); //Since it's an inner class, Bar should be able to be called directly
}


protected void onPostExecute(Integer... result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Completed. Total size: "+result);
    if(myProgressDialog != null && myProgressDialog.isShowing()){
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

private void dirChecker(String dir)
{
    File f = new File(location + dir);
    if(!f.isDirectory())
    {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
} }
```

this is how i call it in my activity
Archives.java

```
String zipFile = o.getPath();
    String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filePath;

    Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation, Archive.this);
    d.execute();
```

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try removing the conditional to dismiss it. `isShowing()` is from the Dialog class and it's possible it's returning false.

Comment: Thanks but I tried it already but its not working.

Comment: You'd better to not reference context and ui elements in your async task to avoid memory leak. Using callback and weakReference is much more better (example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567489/1469481). Then it will be more easy for you to logs callback methods calls and understand what really happens.
Your doInBackground() return null, I don't know if it can be a problem.

Comment: no i Think it is not because of `return null` but because of the method onPostExecute is never used. thats what it say in my code i dont know why :(

Comment: but thank you for your answer, i try to read about callbacks and weakReference.

Comment: onPostExecute(Integer... result) should be onPostExecute(Integer result)

Comment: The subject of your post should have been: onPostExecute never called.

Comment: I think @greenapps is onto something. I notice you have no overrides, and `Integer... result` is incorrect. I think if you use the @Override annotation, it'll tell you it isn't overriding.